# React find 3 highest values in an array

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have been trying to find the highest value in my constantly changing array. What I need is to have an array that changes acording to input (which I have) and a table that shows the  three highest values of that array and changes along with the array values. I used the Math.max, but I always get NaN as my answer.
This is my code:

```
   const array = [
    Weighted1,
    Weighted2,
    Weighted3,
    Weighted4,
    Weighted5,
    Weighted6,
    Weighted7,
    Weighted8,
    Weighted9,
    Weighted10,
    Weighted11,
    Weighted12,
  ];

  const [First, setFirst] = useState("");
  const [Second, setSecond] = useState("");
  const [Third, setThird] = useState("");
 
  /*
  useEffect(() => {
    setFirst(Math.max(array));
  }, [array]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setSecond(array.splice(array.indexOf(one), 1), Math.max(array));
  }, [array, one]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setThird(array.splice(array.indexOf(Second), 1));
  }, [array, Second]);
*/
```

Mytable has these two tipes of values, one is the weighted (all those zeros) and the other is the names I want to be displayed depending on the weighted next to it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jyDX.png)

Comment: `Math.max(...array)`, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your `useEffect()` to listens to the changing input and sort the array via: `Array.sort()`. After this you can set your use last 3 items in that array as your values.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const sortedArray = yourInputArray.sort();
    setFirst(sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 1])
    setSecond(sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 2])
    setThird(sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 3])
  }, [yourInputArray]);
```

A better approach would be storing your input values as a sorted array and using that directly in the component.

```
const [sortedArray, setSortedArray] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  setSortedArray(yourInputArray.sort());
}, [yourInputArray]);

{sortedArray && (
  <>
    <p>1: {sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 1]}</p>
    <p>2: {sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 2]}</p>
    <p>3: {sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 3]}</p>
  <>
)}
```

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: And please note that the first solution was to illustrate how you can 1 useEffect to handle several operations at once. It is not good practice.

Comment: The second solution is a better example of how you can think about the data that you store.

Comment: It aims to keep it simple: `receive data => sort the data in the right order => store that data in a useState  => use that useState variable to display UI`

Comment: With this approach there is a single source of truth. Your data is the sorted array and the UI displays that data.

Comment: What if I had to asign a name for each case of the set*** outcomes? For example if the first answer is the first variable in the array it gives back not the number, but the corresponding name in the table nex to which was that value.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you. Could you give examples of what that data looks like?

Comment: Often you see something like this:
`const yourInputArray = [{label: 'Chris', value: 9}, {label: 'Bob', value: 2}, {label: 'Tom', value: 5}, {label: 'Patrick', value: 4},]`.
You can sort that array by value of each object using: `const sortedArray = yourInputArray.sort((a, b) => (a.value > b.value) ? 1 : -1)`

Comment: I updated my main question to put an image for referance

Comment: You need a way to link your labels / names to the values (your weights). You mentioned that the values of the weights are constantly changing. Can you show an example of the input you receive in `array`

Comment: If you just have an array of names fx `const names = ["narai", "kovotojas", etc]`, and an array of input values that are changing: `const array = [99, 13, etc]`. then you need a way to link the name to that value.